# why does the output change when i change z -1 to z--?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I have the following c++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//looping through arrays backwards
int main() {
    int a[3] {1, 2, 3};
    int x = sizeof(a), y = sizeof(int), z = x / y;
    for(int i = z - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And it outputs `3 2 1`. But if I change the first parameter in the `for` loop to `int i = z--;`, it outpus `2 3 2 1` and I don't understand why. Aren't `z - 1` and `z--` supposed to be the same thing?  Could someone please explain why? Also, I'm a begginer in C++ and I'm learning via the W3Schools tutorial about it. Thanks!

Comment: `z--` returns the value _before_ it's changed. You want `--z`, which returns the new value.

Comment: `z--` is a post decrement. The value is decremented but the returned value is the original value. Use `--z` if you want to decrement the value and have the new value returned.

Comment: Are you talking about the "tutorial" [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_operators.asp)? If so, yes it is clear why you are confused. That doesn't explain anything properly. I recommend you to drop this tutorial and use e.g. one of the [recommended books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `z--` evaluates to `z`, then - as a side effect - `z` is decremented (scheduled according to scheduling rules). This means, you're essentially saying `int i = z` in your loop (and then decrement `z`, but it's not used anymore) - therefore, your code has UB. The `2` printed is purely coincidental, anything might be printed or anything could happen in your code. If you'd like to use `--`, use it as prefix, i. e., `int i = --z`.